# jquery not resetting menu navigation trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I have this script that allows a button to open and close a menu whilst also changing it's class to do a little animation state change depending on open/close,... simple but effective.....

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $navToggle = $('.nav-toggle');
    $(".navbtn").click(function () {
        if($navToggle.hasClass('active')){
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('collapse');
            $navToggle.removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
        else{
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('expand');
            $navToggle.addClass('active');
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    });
```

within the menu is a list with some options (standard) and when one is clicked it performs the following script based on its tag in the list... here's the html and js for that....

html

```
<li>
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>Who are Musability?</a>
 </li>
```

JS

```
 $('.fa-briefcase').parent().on('click', function () {
          $("#colorscreen").remove();
          $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
          $("body").append('<div id="colorscreen" class="animated"></div>');
          $("#colorscreen").addClass("fadeInUpBig");
          $('.fadeInUpBig').css('background-color', 'rgba(13,135,22,0.1)');
          $(".tile-area-main").css({width: "720px"}).load("content.html");
          $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');  
    });
```

**all functions work great separately but when i introduce the functions for the button click fa-briefcase it wont allow me to open the menu again why is this ?**

... on another note (therefore probably a new question at another time) this code is repetitive for all buttons and wonder if there is a way of standardizing the stuff that is repeated into one big function ? not sure about how i would go about it but it isn't the focus of this question , although any advice greatly recieved.

Comment: Should I be including all my html elements in the content.html page  like navbtn maybe that is why it isn't working ? although this doesn't make sense as the tile-area-main is just part of the area of the page and i can still see the navbtn and header eg.

Comment: .... perhaps i need to reload the jquery on the index.html page when i load other pages into it ??

Comment: solved it ! the .load function was loading the entire html page therefore overiding the js already on the index.html page.... this was resolved by loading just the div of the content.html page in this instance ... $(".tile-area-main").css({width: "720px"}).load("content.html #overview");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your `content.html` file contain?
Because if it contains other JavaScript it could be messing with it.

**i.e.**
Instead of `$(".tile-area-main").load("content.html");`
Try `$(".tile-area-main").load("content.html#div");`
Where `#div` is the `div` with the contents you want to `load()` in

**EDIT:** Just noticed your comments, seems like you've fixed it yourself, but glad my method worked :)